# General quintic has Galois group $S_5$ over $\mathbb{Q}(a_0,\dots a_4).$

Tags: galois-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ be the fraction field of the polynomial ring in five variables. I'm considering $f(X)\in K[X]$ given by $f=X^5+a_4X^4+a_3X^3+a_2X^2+a_1X+a_0$ and want to show it has Galois group $S_5$. It's easy to see $f$ is irreducible using Gauss' lemma, so it would suffice e.g to show there's a transposition in $Gal(f)$, but I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: The splitting field is $E=\mathbb{Q}(r_1,\ldots,r_5)$, where $a_4 = -(r_1+\cdots+r_5)$, $a_3 = \sum_{1\leq i\lt j\leq 5}r_ir_j,\ldots,a_0 = -(r_1\cdots r_5)$. It should be clear that any permutation of $r_1,\ldots,r_5$ induces a different automorphism of $E$ over $K$.

Comment: I don't understand why all $5!$ permutations actually lead to $K$- automorphisms.

Comment: Actually, I think my concern is that I don't understand why an automorphism of $E$ which permutes the $r_i\in E$ in some arbitrary way exists. Given that such a thing exists, I do agree it would be a $K$-automorphism. Are the $r_i$ in some sense free in $E$, so I can permute them however I like?

Comment: The easiest way is to work the other way around: Start with $E=\mathbb{Q}(r_1,\ldots,r_5)$ where $r_1,\ldots,r_5$ are variables; define $s_1,\ldots,s_5$ to be the elementary symmetric functions on $r_1,\ldots,r_5$. Then $s_1,\ldots,s_5\in E$, so we can consider the subfield $\mathbb{Q}(s_1,\ldots,s_5)$, which is none other than your $K$. Then show that $K$ is the fixed field of the automorphisms defined by $S_5$ acting on $r_1,\ldots,r_5$, and use Artin's Theorem (Theorem V.2.15 in Hungerford, Theorem VI.1.8 in Lang Rev. 3rd Edition) to conclude $E$ is Galois over $K$ with group $S_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I note in the comments, the simplest way is to work backwards, from the splitting field to the field you start with, if you have the appropriate theorems on hand.

**Theorem** (Artin) Let $K$ be a field, and let $G$ be a finite group of automorphisms of $K$, of order $n$. Let $k$ be the fixed field of $G$. Then $K$ is a finite Galois extension of $k$, and its Galois group is $G$. We have $[K:k]=n$.

Here is the sketch of the proof that appears in Lang's *Algebra* (revised 3rd Edition), where the Theorem is Theorem VI.1.8 (page 264).

*Proof sketch*. Let $\alpha\in K$ and pick $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_r$ a maximal set of elements of $G$ such that $\sigma_1(\alpha),\ldots,\sigma_r(\alpha)$ are distinct. If $\tau\in G$, then $(\tau\sigma_1(\alpha),\ldots,\tau\sigma_r(\alpha))$ differs from $(\sigma_1(\alpha),\ldots,\sigma_r(\alpha))$ by a permutation, so $\alpha$ is a root of
$$ f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^r \Bigl(x - \sigma_i(\alpha)\Bigr).$$
This $f$ has coefficients in $k$ and is separable. So every element of $K$ is the root of a separable polynomial of degree at most $n$ with coefficients in $k$, which splits over $K$, so $K$ is Galois, and $[K:k]\leq n$. So the Galois group includes $G$ has order at most $n$, hence equals $G$. $\Box$

So now proceed "backwards". Let $r_1,\ldots,r_5$ be variables, and let $E=\mathbb{Q}(r_1,\ldots,r_5)$. Let $S_5$ act on $E$ by permuting the variables (these are automorphisms, because they are induced by the corresponding automorphism $\mathbb{Q}[r_1,\ldots,r_5]\to\mathbb{Q}[r_1,\ldots,r_5]$).

By the [Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials), the fixed field of $E$ under the action of $S_5$ is precisely $k=\mathbb{Q}(s_1,\ldots,s_5)$, where $s_1,\ldots,s_5$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials on $r_1,\ldots,r_5$, so by Artin's Theorem, $E$ is Galois over $k$, with Galois group $S_5$.

It is now easy to verify that we can establish an isomorphism between your $K$ and $k$ that makes $E$ the splitting field of $f$, showing what you want.